# Finding n-th term of a sequence of functions

Tags: functions, recursion

Lets say, I have the following series of functions,

$f_1=a+1$
$f_2=a^2+2a+1$
$f_3=a^3+3a^2+3a+1$
Assume that $f_4, f_5,$ and $f_6$ are also known. However $f_n$ is not known as a function of $n$.

From $f_1 ...f_6$, is it possible to reverse engineer the formula for $f_n$ using *Mathematica*?

For the sample sequence given above, I should get, $f_n=(a+1)^n$.

Is such a feature available in *Mathematica*? If so, can you provide links to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Take a look at `FindSequenceFunction`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways to proceed, but the most straightforward is `FindSequenceFunction`, moreover we can use as well `FindLinearRecurrence` with `RSolve` or even `Factor` since it can provide obvious hints to make adequate conclusions.

### Factor

```
Factor @ {a + 1, a^2 + 2 a + 1, a^3 + 3 a^2 + 3 a + 1}
```

> ```
> {1 + a, (1 + a)^2, (1 + a)^3}
> ```

Now we can simply conclude  that the general term is `(1 + a)^n`.

### FindLinearRecurrence

Let's try `FindLinearRecurrence` giving the linear recurrence generating a given sequence of functions:

```
FindLinearRecurrence[{a + 1, a^2 + 2 a + 1, a^3 + 3 a^2 + 3 a + 1}] // Simplify
```

> ```
> {1 + a}
> ```

now it might be the best way to use e.g. `RSolve`:

```
RSolve[{f[n + 1] == (a + 1) f[n], f[1] == a + 1}, f[n], n]
```

> ```
> {{f[n] -> (1 + a)^n}}
> ```

### FindSequenceFunction

A bit more straightforward way would be `FindSequenceFunction` yielding the result in terms of a pure function (if not specified the independent variable):

```
FindSequenceFunction[{a + 1, a^2 + 2 a + 1, a^3 + 3 a^2 + 3 a + 1, 
                      1 + 4 a + 6 a^2 + 4 a^3 + a^4}]
```

> ```
>   (1 + a)^#1 &
> ```

or just what you'd expect in traditional form (when the variable is specified):

```
FindSequenceFunction[{a + 1, a^2 + 2 a + 1, a^3 + 3 a^2 + 3 a + 1, 
                      1 + 4 a + 6 a^2 + 4 a^3 + a^4}, n]// TraditionalForm
```

[image]