# How to Solve a Sequence in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, sequence

Given the input and the output, how do you interpolate a function in *Mathematica*?

For example if you know that

$f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$, $f(2)=\frac{1}{3}$, $f(3)=\frac{1}{4}$,... how would you solve for $f(n)$

I guess what I am really asking is how would one solve a sequence in *Mathematica*?

Comment: See also: [(11389)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11389),
[(24767)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24767),
[(38128)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38128)

Answer (score 1):

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6}, n]
```

> `1/(1 + n)`